# Breath Sensor: A low range pressure sensor that won't be affected by humidity

Tags: pressure, sensors, electrical

I am designing a device that will measure the force of a breath through a tube. A small differential pressure sensor like this https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/MPX10DP/MPX10DP-ND/464046 would be ideal but I believe that the humidity from the breath would impact the pressure reading. What kind of small, cheap pressure sensor could I use that would perform in a humid environment?

Answer (score 1):

Put the sensor inside a membrane like a balloon so that it can detect pressure change without the humidity.